# Why matlab symbolic solver cannot find the root of this equation?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have an equation

```
F1(c) = c+0.5*sqrt{2*c}-(4*c/3)*sqrt(2*c)-1/6
```

I can plot this function for c in (0,1/8). And it is clearly an increasing function  that cross 0 line around c = 0.04. However, when I use

```
solve(F1==0,c,'MaxDegree',3)
```

It outputs 2 imaginary roots. It is very puzzling. I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to ask solve to only return real solutions:

> solve(eqn, x, 'Real', true)